# Why does grid-span affect the height of each card?

Tags: css

I want to span my first card so it takes 2 columns instead of 1, but i want to keep the height the same as it is, but once i set span 1 / 3 it doubles the height.

Link for the pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxNJ2.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJfWl.jpg

```
<div class="grid-3 grid_gap-2 py-6">
            <div class="about-card p3 grid_span-1">
              <h3 class="text-center p1">Our Community</h3>
              <div class="img-container">
                <img src="./images/aboutimg1.jpg" alt="" class="img" />
              </div>
              <p class="py-2">
                <strong>Lorem ipsum dolor</strong> sit amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. Eos debitis qui quis quasi harum unde
                voluptatem dolore nesciunt natus. Dolorum suscipit, ad est
                quibusdam quos unde iure, perferendis quasi illo sit fugit!
                Libero, totam tempore?
              </p>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid_span-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Presumably because the image is not being constrained in size.

Comment: I´ve removed the image and it still does the same thing :/

Comment: Perhaps you could demonstrate the issue in a [mcve]

Comment: Found out why, on my img container i am using padding-top: 75%

Which means when i span my card it doubles in width and so the height of my image which is based using the padding top of the relative parent will also double, making it 150%.

this video helped me figure this out 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF5kD6QEEag